# how to check which version of graph api is called in Python

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Graph API version 3.3 is ending on 3rd, August 2021.
I am unable to see the versioned graph API calls on the APP dashboard(might be Facebook removed it).

**Facebook-SDK** version is **3.1.0**

In my code:

```
self.fb_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(version='7.0')
posts = self.fb_graph.get_connections(id=page_id, connection_name='feed', 
                       fields=fields, since=date_range, until=date_range, access_token=page_access_token)
```

I get the data using this. But when I use code `self.fb_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(version='3.2')`.

Even version 3.2 is no more but I am getting data using this too.

I am unable to get the Facebook graph API calls version.
How can I get the version number of API calls either using code or on any dashboard?

Comment: SDK version and Graph API version are two different things. For Graph API you are specifying version='7.0'.

Comment: I need to verify that api call is with version 7.0 for graph api.